# Close message is missing "And Fantasy"

Tags: bug, status-completed

[image: missing "and/or fantasy"]
Can we change this to:

> Questions on Science Fiction **And
>   Fantasy** are expected to generally
>   relate to science fiction **or
>   fantasy** within the scope defined in
>   the faq.

?

Comment: Working on it. (:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Geoff took care of this. \o/

[image: SFF]